# I have skimage version 0.12. I want to specifically download version 0.14. How do i do that?

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, scikit-image

I've been trying to install version 0.14 of sklearn but I couldn't do it in ubuntu with python version 3.

How can I do that?

Comment: `skimage` or `sklearn`? Your question probably belongs on SuperUser because Stack Overflow is only for programming questions.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have't provided information about what you have tried, you can start trying to upgrade skimage  with conda or pip

```
    conda update scikit-image
```

Another thing that you can try is

```
    pip3 install --upgrade scikit-image==0.14
```